# Password protection, while keeping track of who is who

Tags: security, php

I maintain a farmer market site. Part of the site includes a database with all of the different farmers and what they are harvesting this week.

Currently I have one set of admin pages that are hidden from the public by the fact that I have not told anyone where they are at. With the admin pages I edit the data as needed. As more farmers get involved, it is getting to be a pain updating their data and I want to set it up so each farmer can signup, log on with their own password and edit what they have at market this week without me getting involved.

I have seen plenty of scrips for password protecting a page. The ones that I have seen have been set up so that once a user is signed in they can view everything and there does not appear to be an easy way to keep track of who signed in.

How do I build password protection, while keeping track of who is who, so that I can build the custom admin pages on the fly? Any tips or best practices to keep in mind?

Thanks,

Brandan
P.S. I have been using PHP and SQLite

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want anything more special than having each user logging in and editing his own information?

Comment: This is a very broad question that probably cannot be answered effectively here. It sounds as if you need to be looking at a CMS. You can google that and choose one that suits. It'll save you reinventing a very big wheel.

Comment: Currently i have a admin page which is hidden from public by the fact that i haven't told anybody.... Lol. You are asking for trouble dude....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these scripts that you find online.

All it boils down to is:

- Signup page to gather user details, upon save check each field is valid (ie. use regular expressions to check email address is valid), also check all required fields are completed
- If the above all checks out, then save to database AFTER you have sanitized the data (we don't want any SQL injections now!)
- I'd recommend at least saving the password as a hash, so use something like `md5()` and i'd use a salt key too (so something like MD5($password.$salt)) - the SALT can be a timestamp of when the user signed up, a random string of letters/numbers (which I'd recommend) - and save this as well in the database.
- When the user signs in, sanitize the data, check username exists and grab the salt key of that matching entry, then MD5 the incoming password with the SALT key and see if the strings match
- Save some kind of flag to $_SESSION, eg. `$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;` then at the top of each protected page you can do some like in the example below
- You could also then save a timestamp (`time()`) or  datetime (`date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`) to the database under a column labelled last_logged_in

I know this isn't a load of code but it forms a basic guide to get you started

**Example For Above**

```
if($_SESSION['loggedin'] !== true){
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
} else {
    // rest of protected page
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very clear to do list, that will help a lot. What do I need for keeping track of who has which sessions while keeping things secure? I am guessing that I should do more than just assign the userID to a variable in the session when they log in and then check for the variable before I sever a page? Or is it really that simple?

Comment: It would also be a good idea to store something like User ID in a session as well as a token (where a new one is generated and stored in database and session each a user logs in) - you can then compare the user id to the token, if they don't match - auto log the user out as a security precaution. There are a few other minor things you could add, such as a timeout (so store last action in the database as a time, and auto log the user out if the time has been too long). If this has been helpful, feel free to tick it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure each user has a unique log-in (preferably e-mail) and password. Then create a form with 2 input fields for username and password, and after postback, match the values against the database. If the data is a match, store the user_id (or more user data) in a session.

Answer (score 0):

For finding out who is who, I would use sessions($_SESSION variable)

Make some simple login page, set some id`s or use emails as login, if you want you can make some registration page too.

Use random strings as passwords for users, send it to them and tell them to change password on first login.

DO NOT STORE PASSWORD IN DB. Use only password hashes(sha512 for example). If you want to improve security use some server salt or user salt.
On every login compare hash of password that user put in with password stored in db.
Watch out for SQL injection vulnerabilities, i would advise to use PDO and insert variables as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Basic HTTP-Auth](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) or you build your own based on [Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). Tracking the user is very easy in both cases (Unique name and Session id respectively).